# Unusual equation (solving)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have the following representation of $z$ in terms of $s$, where both $z,s\in \mathbb{R}$ and $|s|<1$:

$$e^{s+2}\sqrt{1-s^2}=z$$

Now, how can I express $s$ in terms of $z$?

I first attacked the problem by taking logarithms:

$$2s + \log (1-s^2) = \log (\frac{z^2}{e^4})$$

Or

$$2s + \log (1-s) + \log(1+s) = \log (\frac{z^2}{e^4})$$

And then developing a Taylor Series expansion of the remaining logarithm, with no success (I got stuck). Changes of variables such as $s+1=t$ did not work for me neither. Besides, I do not imagine any other way to solve this problem.

I do not mind getting something like a Lambert-W function or similar as a result.

Am I missing anything here? What strategy shall I use?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you need to find the inverse function of $e^{s-2}\sqrt{1-s^2}$

Comment: First work out the "inverse" domain for $z$, as you want to get a function that maps $z$-values to $s$-values.  More than likely there is no simple expression for $s$ in terms of $z$, but you should be able to create a practical solver for $s$ given $z$ using familiar root-finding algorithms.

Comment: Why do you expect an explicit formula for the inverse of this function ? It is likely that no such formula exists.

Comment: @hardmath Yes, In fact it is equivalent to say that I am lookimg for the inverse of the funcion $f : [-1,1] \to \mathbb{R}$. Rather than an approximate solution, I was trying to find the exact one.

Comment: @tristan Why is it likely for it not to exist? (I do not expect that to happen, but I think that just because of pure intuition/hope)

Comment: A graph of the function $f$ should help you sort out what $z$ values are valid to use in finding $s$ values.

Comment: @hardmath Gotcha, thank you for pointing out that fact. Anyway, can't we represent $s$ in terms of $z$ as a "multivalued function"?

Comment: If you replace the square root as $\sqrt{1-s^2}\to\sqrt{1-s}$, then the inverse function of $g(s)=f^2(s) = s \exp(s)(1-s) =y$ is $s(y)= \frac{1}{2}\left( W(-2y/(ae^2))+2\right)$, as we can check explicitly: $g(s(y))=a (e^{2s(y)}-s(y)e^{2s(y)}) = -\frac{a}{2} W(\dots) e^{W(\dots)+2} = -\frac{a}{2} e^2 (-2 y/(ae^2)) = y$. However, with the square I don't know how to solve it. Neither does Wolfram Alpha, btw.

Comment: um...substituting $ s = \sin \theta$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rearrange:

$$e^{s+2}\sqrt{1-s^2}=z\iff e^{2s}(s^2-1)=-e^{-4}z^2$$

and use [Lagrange inversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LagrangeInversionTheorem.html):

$$e^{2s}(s^2-1)=a\implies s=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1}}{ds^{n-1}}\left.\left(\frac{s-1}{e^{2s}(s-1)(s+1)}\right)^n\right|_1$$

[General Leibniz rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule) gives:

$$\frac{d^{n-1}}{ds^{n-1}}e^{-2ns}(s+1)^{-n}=\sum_{m=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}m\frac{d^{n-1-m}}{ds^{n-1-m}}e^{-2ns}\frac{d^m}{ds^m}(s+1)^{-n}$$

Summing uses [Bessel K](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=BesselK):

$$\boxed{s=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-e^{-4}z^2n)^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}n!}\operatorname K_{\frac12-n}(2n)}$$

[shown here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=evaluate+e%5E%28s%2B2%29%E2%88%9A%281-s%5E2%29%2Cs%3D1-sum%5B%28-7+%5E2%2Fe%5E4.0%29%5En%2Fn%21+%28%28-n%29%5En+BesselK%281%2F2+-+n%2C+2+n%29%29%2F%28sqrt%28n%29+sqrt%28%CF%80%29%29%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C40%7D%5D). There is another branch of the inverse function too

Comment: There is a way to get both branches by inverting $e^{\pm 2\sqrt x}(x-1),x^2=s$