# How can I solve the equation $y=e^{\cos(x)}\sin(x)$?

Tags: special-functions, inverse-function, lambert-w

I was reading about the Lambert W function, and I want to know if it is possible to extend the ideas to solve the given equation for real values of x. $$y=\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)} $$
I know that the W function is only for equations of this form: $$W(x)e^{W(x)}=x$$
I would like any help or ideas regarding this problem, or about the impossibility of solving it.
Thanks in advance.
[Note: Wolfram|Alpha is unable to solve the equation]
[image: graph]

Specifications:

I would like an explicit inverse function to $$x\rightarrow{\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)}}$$ not a numerical solution. The special function $W$ can be used in the explicit form. The original function has the restricted domain of $[-\arccos(a),\arccos(a)]$ for $a=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$ and the inverse should have the domain $[-\sqrt{a}e^a,\sqrt{a}e^a]$ for the same $a$

[This question was migrated from MathOverflow]

Comment: Substituting $z = cos(x)$, your equation implies $y^2 = (1 - z^2) e^{2z}$. So, I think your function has an explicit inverse (in terms of a given set of special functions) iff the function $f(z) = (1 - z^2) e^{2z}$ has an explicit inverse.

Comment: Do you think that the function you have written has a closed form explicit inverse? @ZoeAllen

Comment: Consider the only possible special function in your arsenal to be $W$

Comment: You could obtain an accurate approximation of the root. If of any interest, just tell.

Comment: What do you mean with "solve y=f(x)" ? "Solve for $x$" ?

Comment: We could always if we want to solve a new equation we cannot solve with the current tools invent a new "closed form inverse" as it was done with the Lambert-W function. But this has little merit. Only in cases were the function can solve a wide class of equations (as the Lambert-W function) , this can be useful.

Comment: @Peter I was asking for a way to define a solution for x in terms of y using only the W function, not creating a new special function.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici though approxiamting the root was not my intention, I would be glad to hear about the technique to do so

Comment: If you want to see the approximation (tell me if it is the case), I should make an answer tomorrow early morning. Cheers :-)

Comment: My actual target is the explicit inverse, and I would be glad if you could elaborate (in your answer) about how (4) corresponds to the equation you reduced my question to. But I would also like to hear about the approximation technique (you can give that as a comment or include it in your answer) @ClaudeLeibovici

Comment: Similar equation solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2592455/unusual-equation-solving/4718920#4718920)

Comment: @TymaGaidash actually I was looking for a closed form solution. But thanks still

Comment: @SohamSaha The only “closed form” is with a specialized “generalized Lambert W function”, but it is not very common and does not appear in Mathematica/Maple etc. Therefore, the series expansion is likely the most effective solution, as it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y=\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)}$$
$$\sin(x)e^{\cos(x)}=y$$

As the comments propose:

$x\to\arccos(z)$:
$$\sin(\arccos(z))e^z=y$$
$$(1-z^2)(e^z)^2=y^2$$
$$(1-z^2)(e^z)^2-y^2=0\tag{1}$$

We see, for general $y$, this equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($z,e^z$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $z$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (elementary operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

We see, for algebraic general $y$, equation (1) is an algebraic equation of both $z$ and $e^z$ with no univariate factor. The equation cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) therefore.

$$(1-z^2)e^{2z}=y^2$$
$z\to\frac{t}{2}$:
$$-\frac{1}{4}(-4+t^2)e^t=y^2$$
$$(t^2-4)e^t=-4y^2$$

As the other answer proposes:
We see, we cannot solve this equation in terms of Lambert W, but in terms of Generalized Lambert W. See page 3 in [Mező/Baricz 2017].

$$(t+2)(t-2)e^t=-4y^2$$
$$t=W\left(^{-2,+2}_{};-4y^2\right)$$
$$z=\frac{1}{2}W\left(^{-2,+2}_{};-4y^2\right)$$
$$x=\arccos\left(\frac{1}{2}W\left(^{-2,+2}_{};-4y^2\right)\right)$$

So we have a [closed form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) for $x$, and the series representations of Generalized Lambert W give some hints for calculating $x$.

A closed-form expression is a placeholder for its [analytic representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression#Analytic_expression), and furthermore, we can use its algebraic properties and special values.

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Answer (score 2):

As @Zoe Allen commented, squaring and letting $z=\cos(x)$, we have to solve for $z$ the equation
$$y^2=(1-z^2)\,e^{2z}\qquad \implies\qquad  e^{-2z}=\frac {1-z^2} {y^2}$$ which has a solution  in terms  of the [generalized Lambert function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999) (have a look at equation $(4)$).

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little, I think the paper is a little out of my range

Comment: @SohamSaha. About approximation ?

Comment: No about the explicit inverse method

Comment: How does (4) correspond to the form you reduced my question to?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici could you please correct this in your answer: Page 3 of your reference is mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

*For an approximate solution of the equation.*

We want to inverse
$$y=\sin(x)\,e^{\cos(x)}$$ for
$$0 \leq x \leq \cos^{-1} (a)\qquad\qquad 0 \leq y\leq \sqrt a\, e^a \qquad \text{where} \qquad a=\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$$

We have
$$e^{\cos(x)}=e \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a_n}{b_n} x^{2n}$$ The coefficients $a_n$ and $b_n$ form respectively sequences $A047689$ and $A047690$ in $OEIS$.

So, we know the series expansion of $y$
$$y=e \sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\, c_n\,x^{2n+1}$$ the first $c_n$ forming the sequence
$$ \left\{1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{31}{120},\frac{379}{5040},\frac{1639}{90720
   },\frac{150349}{39916800},\frac{4373461}{6227020800},\frac{39074491
   }{326918592000},\cdots\right\}$$

To give an idea of the accuracy, using only the terms given in the above table
$$\Phi=\int_0^{\cos^{-1}(a)} \Big(\sin(x)\,e^{\cos(x)}-S_{15}\Big)^2\,dx=1.80\times 10^{-12}$$

Using [power series reversion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesReversion.html) and noting $\color{red}{t=\frac y e}$, is obtained
$$x=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n\, t^{2n+1}$$ the first coefficients being
$$\left\{1,\frac{2}{3},\frac{43}{40},\frac{757}{336},\frac{3091}{576},
   \frac{582581}{42240},\frac{22334047}{599040},\frac{1872179}{17920},\frac{52772932189}{175472640},\cdots\right\}$$

Some results obtained with the $c_n$ given above

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
y & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
 0.05 & 0.0183981233 &  0.0183981233 \\
 0.10 & 0.0368212081 &  0.0368212081 \\
 0.15 & 0.0552944907 &  0.0552944907 \\
 0.20 & 0.0738437638 &  0.0738437638 \\
 0.25 & 0.0924956771 &  0.0924956771 \\
 0.30 & 0.1112780635 &  0.1112780635 \\
 0.35 & 0.1302203043 &  0.1302203043 \\
 0.40 & 0.1493537459 &  0.1493537459 \\
 0.45 & 0.1687121881 &  0.1687121881 \\
 0.50 & 0.1883324635 &  0.1883324635 \\
 0.55 & 0.2082551405 &  0.2082551405 \\
 0.60 & 0.2285253893 &  0.2285253893 \\
 0.65 & 0.2491940675 &  0.2491940675 \\
 0.70 & 0.2703191012 &  0.2703191082 \\
 0.75 & 0.2919672740 &  0.2919673012 \\
 0.80 & 0.3142165817 &  0.3142166781 \\
 0.85 & 0.3371593815 &  0.3371597014 \\
 0.90 & 0.3609066768 &  0.3609076750 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Notice that we can make a simpler approximation transforming the series into the coresponding $[2n+1,2n]$ Padé approximant of it $P_n$ such as
$$P_2=t\,\frac {1-\frac{559253 }{209478}t^2+\frac{18722873
   }{21995190} t^4} {1-\frac{698905 }{209478}t^2+\frac{3911235
   }{1955128}t^4 }$$ whose error is $\sim \frac 2 5 t^{11}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please which software you used for creating the table y-estimate-solution?

Comment: @SohamSaha. Nothing special : the estimate is given and Newton for the exact solution